# Setup local WiFi via using an existing secured network (university department)

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, speakers

We've been looking at installing some WiFi speakers in our workshop (Amazon Echo/Bose equivalent) to listen to Spotify collectively rather than having a set of different radios/speakers competing for audio.

As we're in a university department, all of the available WiFi networks are WPA2-enterprise, which, at present, isn't supported by any WiFi speakers that I've been able to find (I think its difficult for the speaker to actually login and remember the right set of credentials).

The obvious solution is to setup some kind of local WiFi 'network'. I've been able to successfully do this with my MacBook using a few other questions found here on SuperUser, but generally this is non-ideal, since if I then leave the room with my laptop to go to a meeting etc, then the audio goes off.

What would be ideal is to gave a way of setting up a WiFi hotspot (we're perfectly allowed to add additional routers etc so long as they have some security) that would allow us to use an existing network. Is this possible, to take a secure network, and broadcast a WiFi signal (passworded, but not secured using the standard university browser based login)?    If it helps, anything plugged into an ethernet cable within the department just 'automatically' has access to the internet.

Comment: Looks exactly like the kind of thing I would use a Raspberry Pi for.

Answer (score 0):

Really, if you just add another router and connect the Ethernet cable to its Internet port, then it would allow the speakers to run.  If that doesn't seem viable to you then many SBC (Single-Board Computer) type systems can probably fill you request fairly well.  Raspberry Pi, Arduino, Olimex, as well as many others would be good candidates so long as they have both a LAN port and WiFi capabilities.  Dual or even Single WiFi might work, but you'd have to do more of a set up to get it to work right, (one WiFi for your University connection, one for your speakers).  Spotify runs on Linux, and many of the SBC systems come with some form of Linux, so you should be set there.  I don't know what system requirements are needed for Spotify on Linux, but I should think that at lest 512M-1G should suite your needs, (I'd lean towards the 1G-2G systems just to be safe).  Once you set up the OS, you can install OpenSSH to be able to remotely access the system, which means you won't need to have a monitor, keyboard, or mouse plugged into it to use it.